# Mosquitto broker not functioning with all configurations

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto, broker

I did the following changes in mosquitto.conf

```
password_file "\etc\mosquitto\passwordfile.txt"
allow_anonymous false
```

But still when i send the command

```
mosquitto_pub -u admin -P (wrong password) -m "1" -t "topic"
```

and

```
mosquitto_sub -u admin -t "topic"
```

I am still receiving, at the broker the message I am publishing. Should that be NOT happening?

i created the password file using

```
mosquitto_passwd -c "etc\mosquitto\passwordfile.txt" admin
```

I am getting a feeling I am doing a very silly mistake. But just cant put a finger on it

Comment: Update the question (do not try to add it as a comment) with log output from when mosquitto is started so we see if it's complaining about the config file

Comment: Also what OS are you running on? Because you seam to be mixing windows and unix file path separators

Comment: What do you  mean by "log output from when the mosquitto is started"? I am running Windows OS. I open two terminals and communicate between them using mosquitto_sub and mosquitto_pub commands.

Comment: When mosquitto starts it outputs information about what ports it's listening on and information about what password file it's using

Comment: How do i find it? I searched in the mosquitto folder. There is no log or .log file present

Comment: Looking at the Ubuntu packaged install it looks like they have disabled logging which is not helpful. Look in the mosquitto.conf for the logging section and edit it to something sensible (there are comments to explain). Restart mosquitto and then add the logs

Comment: I did that. I changed 
"log_dest stderr"
to
"log_dest \etc\mosquitto\log.txt"

After restarting the broker and sending multiple Pub Sub messages also, the Log file remains empty.